# Hi, i'm new to gem5. is there a way to make simulation for a CPU-GPU heterogeneous computing？

Tags: gem5

i'm new to gem5.
May i ask is there a way to make simulation for a CPU-GPU heterogeneous computing？
the gem5-gpu is too old and poorly maintained, so it is better to use GCN3.

For example, i want to simulate that:
1.CPU load several data from CPU memory and handle them.
2.CPU send them to GPU memory
3.GPU fetch data from GPU memory and handle them.
4.GPU write the data back to CPU memory

Is there a way to achieve this in Gem5?

Sincerely ask for help.

I find no example about CPU-GPU heterogeneous computing. Is there any example here?